# perl Grouping things and hierarchical matching

Tags: perl

I've been testing Perl regex code what is written in the `perlrequick` section on [*Grouping things and hierarchical matching*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#Grouping-things-and-hierarchical-matching)

This my Perl code

```
my $t = "housecats";
my ($m) = $t =~ m/house(cat|)/;
print $m;
```

The output is **cat**, but should be as written in the documentation

```
/house(cat|)/;  # matches either 'housecat' or 'house'
```

What is wrong? Is there something amiss?

Comment: What are you expecting to get? Because `$m` is going to to be the content of the capturing bracket ( `cat` or `''`) not the whole word.

Answer (score 1):

You probably misunderstood the comment. It means that

```
for my $t (qw( housecats house )) {
    my ($m) = $t =~ /house(cat|)/;
    print "[$m]\n";
}
```

will print

```
[cat]
[]
```

i.e. the regex will match both `housecat` and `house`. If the pattern didn't match at all then `$m` would be `undef`

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing with this code

```
my $t = "housecats";
my ($m) = $t =~ m/house(cat|)/;
print $m;
```

is copying the first *capture* into `$m`. Parentheses `()` in the pattern indicate which parts of the matching string to capture and store into built-in variables `$1`, `$2` etc. You can have as many captures as you like, and they are numbered in the same order as the opening parentheses appears in the pattern

What `perlrequick` is talking about is what constitutes a *successful match*. Normally you would write

```
my $t = "housecats";
my $success = $t =~ m/house(cat|)/;
print $success ? "matched\n" : "no match\n";
```

This code produces

```
matched
```

as the document describes. If you set `$t` to `housemartin` then the result is the same because the regex pattern successfully finds `house`. But if `$t` is `hosepipe` then we see `no match` because the string contains neither `house` nor `housecat`

If you need to extract parts of the matched string then you must use captures as described above. You can access the whole string that was matched by accessing the built-in variable `$&`, but doing so causes unacceptable performance degradation in all but the latest Perl versions. For backward-compatability you should simply *capture* the whole pattern by writing

```
my $t = "housecats";
my ($m) = $t =~ m/(house(cat|))/;
print $m;
```

which produces `housecat` as you expected. It also sets the values of `$1` and `$2` to `housecat` and `cat` respectively

Answer (score 0):

```
my $t = "housecats";
my ($m) = $t=~m/house(cat|)/gn;
print $m;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.